# Can Debreu's axiomatization of cardinal utility use equivalent relation instead of preference relation?

Tags: microeconomics, decision-theory

> Theorem ([Debreu 1959][1] page 9, 10) Let $X_i$ be space of real numbers. *If $\succsim$ is continuous, rational, independent and at least three factors are essential, then there exist functions $u_i:X_i\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that*
> $$
> x\succsim y\iff \sum_{i=1}^n u_i (x_i) \geqslant \sum_{i=1}^n u_i (y_i).
> $$

Independent means: $x_Iy\succsim x_Iy'\implies x'_Iy\succsim x'_Iy'$

**Question**: can the preference relation in independence be changed to **equivalence** relation?

Which means:  $x_Iy\sim x_Iy'\implies x'_Iy\sim x'_Iy'$.

Perhaps we need to add some monotonicity conditions.

Comment: Could you please explain the notation $x_Iy$?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a partial answer: The two conditions are equivalent if preferences are strongly monotone. To see this, let $x_Iy\succ x_Iy'$. Let $e=(1,1,\ldots,1)\in\mathbb{R}^n$. By strong monotonicity and continuity, there exists (a unique) $\alpha>0$ such that $x_Iy\sim x_I(y'+\alpha e)$. Then, $x_I'y\sim x_I (y'+\alpha e)\succ x_I'y'$ by the condition and strong monotonicity.